# Passing DateTime strings from different cultures to a service

Tags: c#, datetime, service, datetime-format, culture

I have a Solution with a Windows 10 Desktop Application Project and a Service Project. The Desktop Application starts the service and passes an argument which is a `DateTime` converted to a String. Within the service, the string is being passed to `DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)` but this failed all the time. The culture of my testing system is German but I realized that within the Service, the culture always seems to be en-US (I think because it's running in SYSTEM context). I know that my application is going to run in 16 different countries all over the world. I was thinking if I could somehow get the User culture and use this info within my service to use the second overload of `DateTime.TryParse` where I can specify an `IFormatProvider` but is this the best solution? I basically need a robust solution to pass DateTime strings from different cultures to my service so that I can further work with it. Would it be acceptable to just format the `DateTime` String according to the Service culture before passing it to the Service?

Comment: Why not send the "raw" DateTime.Ticks to the service? Saves you from the hassle of having to deal with strings, no?

Comment: _DateTime converted to a String_.  Why convert to a string at all?  Why not pass a real `DateTime`?  What mechanism are you using to pass the data?  Are you using a WCF service or named pipes or something else?

Comment: @C.Gonzalez That would work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm using a local Windows service and as far as I've seen it only seems to support string[] args as parameter.

Comment: How are you passing the parameter?  Are you hard coding it in the Services dialog?  How do you start the service?

Comment: Service is exclusively started from my desktop application through a ServiceController instance where I'm passing a string[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Desktop Application starts the service and passes an argument which is a DateTime converted to a String.

You can use the [InvariantCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a(v=vs.71).aspx) to communicate between the application and the service:

> The InvariantCulture is useful for storing data that will not be displayed directly to end users. Storing data in a culture-independent format guarantees a known format that does not change. When users from different cultures access the data, it can be formatted appropriately based on the user. For example, if you store DateTime types in a text file, formatted for the InvariantCulture, use the InvariantCulture property when you call the DateTime.ToString method to store the strings and the Date.Parse method to retrieve the strings. This will ensure that the underlying values of the DateTime types do not change when the data is read or written by users from different cultures.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks you!